# dplyr select/distinct keeps brining in a column I don't choose

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with many columns in it. For example:

```
MRN     | Svc_Line...
--------|----------
123456  | Medical
123456  | Medical
987654  | Surgical
...
```

I issue the following commands which all bring back an extra column:

```
dplyr::select(
distinct(
.data = tblPerf
, MRN
    )
)
```

Brings back MRN and Svc_Line

```
dplyr::select(
.data = tblPerf
, MRN
)
```

Brings back MRN and Svc_Line

```
dply::distinct(
.data = tblPerf
, MRN
)
```

brings back MRN and Svc_Line

No matter what columns I try to bring back Svc_Line is always also brought back. It is a `factor`, not sure why this is happening. I have shutdown and restarted my R-Studio session

The table `tblPerf` was put together from another table, `rad_data`. The table `rad_data` has many variables that were created using `mutate()` based upon groupings of other columns. I then did the following:

```
tblPerf <- rad_data %>%
mutate(ord_per_pt_elos = 
       round((enc_order_count/Performance), 4)) %>%
mutate(ord_pty_svcline_ord_elos = 
       round((svcline_ord_per_pt/ord_pty_svc_elos), 4)) %>%
mutate(avg_ord_per_pt_elos = round(avg_ordperenc_ord_pty/ord_pty_elos, 4))
```

And am then trying to select/distinct from that. I have since also done `tblPerf <- tblPerf` in hopes of getting rid of the grouping error. I am now getting the error of:

```
> tblPerf <- tblPerf
> dplyr::select(
+   .data = tblPerf
+   , MRN
+ )
Adding missing grouping variables: `Ord_Pty_Number`, `LIHN_Svc_Line`
# A tibble: 1,715 x 3
# Groups:   Ord_Pty_Number, LIHN_Svc_Line [217]
   Ord_Pty_Number LIHN_Svc_Line    MRN
            <chr>        <fctr>  <chr>
 1          12345       Medical 123456
```

I did not have this issue yesterday

Comment: Is tablPerf grouped ?

Comment: tblPerf does contain variables that were put together based on groupings. I'll update question to show steps to get tblPerf

Comment: If it's grouped, you'll need to explicitly use `ungroup()` to keep those variables from tagging along.

Comment: that worked, even though it did not change anything in the table, thanks @joran

Comment: The grouping information is actually "attached" to the data frame (tibble) as an attribute. So if you run `attributes()` on a grouped df, you'll see that, and other information as well that dplyr and tibble tack on.

Comment: thank you, I did make changes in my code today from yesterday so there must have been an intermediate step I deleted from yesterday

Answer (score 2):

You need to ungroup the dataframe.

```
> tblPerf <- tblPerf %>% ungroup()
> dplyr::select(
+   .data = tblPerf
+   , MRN
+ )
```